# Controle de margem e visualização do arquivo exportado com o .wordExport() (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom dia.

Gostaria de uma ajuda com o comando .wordExport() do JQuery. Eu estou conseguindo exportar o html sem problemas para documento de word, entretanto, quando abro o documento, as margens estão do tamanho default do word ao invés das margens delimitadas no html/css, assim como o arquivo fica no modo de visualização da web ao invés da visualzação de impressão, que é o padrão do word para exibição de arquivos. Sabem como faço para que o documento exporte já na visualização de impressão e com as margens da página delimitadas com o tamanho que eu necessito? Preciso exportar um contrato constantemente, e estou tendo problemas com essa questão.
Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.

Obs.: Por razões específicas, não posso postar o código de html completo, mas o script está assim:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="FileSaver.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.wordexport.js"></script>
<body>
<a class="word-export" href="javascript:void(0)"> Export as .doc </a>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("a.word-export").click(function(event) {
            $(".page-content").wordExport();
        });
    });
    </script>
<div class="page-content">
```

E ai vem o html do documento de word. É muito extenso, e possui informações confidenciais e portanto não posso postar aqui, mas dai pra baixo é só texto editado com css no próprio html(eu converti o documento do word em html usando um conversor online e arrumei na mão o resto)

Obs.: Sim, estou usando jquery 1.11 por que ainda estou testando a funcionalidade de exportar o documento, uma vez que isto ficar pronto vou modificar o código.

Comment: Teu código está como? `wordExport` não é do jQuery, por acaso seria [este](https://github.com/markswindoll/jQuery-Word-Export) plugin?

Comment: Sim, é este plugin.
O código é um documento de word editado em html escondido na página que quero exportar, é bem simples mas muito extenso pra postar aqui, acredito.